# How to make a sequence number ranking in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, row-number, dense-rank

I have data like this:

```
id | md_name      | total_visit
===+==============+============
1  | Nunu Nugraha | 33
2  | Erwin        | 32
3  | Tri Sulistyo | 35
4  | Risdianto    | 24
5  | Erma         | 22
6  | Dwi Sabana   | 19
7  | Ernayanti    | 26
8  | Ali          | 10
9  | Partini      | 13
```

I made the above results with a join code like this:

```
SELECT datamd.id as id,
    datamd.nama_md as md_name,
    COUNT(R.id) as total_visit
    FROM datamd
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, idmd
        FROM rincian_kunjungan WHERE status='1' AND MONTH(tanggal_kunjungan)='$bulan' AND YEAR(tanggal_kunjungan)='$tahun'
    ) AS R
        ON datamd.id = R.idmd WHERE status=1 AND level=8 GROUP BY datamd.id ORDER BY datamd.id
```

And I want to be like this:

```
rank | id | md_name      | total_visit
=====+====+==============+============
  1  | 3  | Tri Sulistyo | 35
  2  | 1  | Nunu Nurgaha | 33
  3  | 2  | Erwin        | 32
  4  | 7  | Ernayanti    | 26
  5  | 4  | Risdianto    | 24
  6  | 5  | Erma         | 22
  7  | 6  | Dwi Sabana   | 19
  8  | 9  | Partini      | 13
  9  | 8  | Ali          | 10
```

Can friends here help me, I have tried using the code below but in the ranking column it is not appropriate

```
SET @number = 0;
SELECT @number:=@number+1 as rank, datamd.id as id,
    datamd.nama_md as md_name,
    COUNT(R.id) as total_visit
    FROM datamd
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, idmd
        FROM rincian_kunjungan WHERE status='1' AND MONTH(tanggal_kunjungan)='$bulan' AND YEAR(tanggal_kunjungan)='$tahun'
    ) AS R
        ON datamd.id = R.idmd WHERE status=1 AND level=8 GROUP BY datamd.id ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: mysql version is 5.6.25

Comment: What does "*it is not appropriate*" mean? Can you please clarify the problem you're having?

Comment: What I mean, when the ranking column is sorted from the smallest to the largest column, the total visits are not sequential, when the total column of my visit is sorted from the largest to the smallest the column rank is also not sequential, when I use the first 2 sortings my total visits are sorted from the biggest to the smallest and the rank column from the smallest to the largest the result remains in the rank column whose numbers are not sequential.

Comment: @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/473F1pvESeWV7jt2qnJrxG/0 you can check here - it works fine

Comment: it did not differ much in my previous code, and the results remained the same can not be sequential in the ranking column

Comment: Put the original query as a subquery to the ranking bit - although, seeing as you have access to application code, I'd handle the ranking there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <del>fight user variables all day or</del> emulate dense rank function in MySQL like so:

```
SELECT main.id, main.md_name, main.total_visit, COUNT(DISTINCT prev.total_visit) + 1 AS rank
FROM datamd AS main
LEFT JOIN datamd AS prev ON prev.total_visit > main.total_visit
GROUP BY main.id, main.md_name, main.total_visit
ORDER BY rank
```

Substitute the "tables" in the above query with the sub queries from your original query:

```
SELECT datamd.id, datamd.nama_md, main.total_visit, COUNT(DISTINCT prev.total_visit) + 1 AS rank
FROM datamd
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idmd, COUNT(*) AS total_visit
    FROM rincian_kunjungan
    WHERE status = '1' AND MONTH(tanggal_kunjungan) = $bulan AND YEAR(tanggal_kunjungan) = $tahun
    GROUP BY idmd
) AS main ON datamd.id = main.idmd
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_visit
    FROM rincian_kunjungan
    WHERE status = '1' AND MONTH(tanggal_kunjungan) = $bulan AND YEAR(tanggal_kunjungan) = $tahun
    GROUP BY idmd
) AS prev ON prev.total_visit > main.total_visit
GROUP BY datamd.id, datamd.nama_md, main.total_visit
ORDER BY rank
```

Comment: I don't understand where it came from "main.total visit"

Comment: This query is based on your data. Seems like you're using a sub query to generate the total_visit column so the "main" table is actually your sub query.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Previously I had made a code that you made but failed, before I also did not understand in your first explanation but after you updated it I understood it and after I tried your code the results were as I expected. Thank you for helping me, may God repay all of your kindness for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

please try using this query :

I have created a table test and inserted the record like this  :

```
select  * from test ;
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | md_name      | total_visit |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | Nunu Nugraha |          33 |
|  2 | Erwin        |          32 |
|  3 | Tri Sulistyo |          35 |
|  4 | Risdianto    |          24 |
|  5 | Erma         |          22 |
|  6 | Dwi Sabana   |          19 |
|  7 | Ernayanti    |          26 |
|  8 | Ali          |          10 |
|  9 | Partini      |          13 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

I have developed query :

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 rank, id, md_name, total_visit
FROM `test` , (SELECT @rownum :=0)r
ORDER BY total_visit DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30


got this result :

+------+----+--------------+-------------+
| rank | id | md_name      | total_visit |
+------+----+--------------+-------------+
|    1 |  3 | Tri Sulistyo |          35 |
|    2 |  1 | Nunu Nugraha |          33 |
|    3 |  2 | Erwin        |          32 |
|    4 |  7 | Ernayanti    |          26 |
|    5 |  4 | Risdianto    |          24 |
|    6 |  5 | Erma         |          22 |
|    7 |  6 | Dwi Sabana   |          19 |
|    8 |  9 | Partini      |          13 |
|    9 |  8 | Ali          |          10 |
```

Comment: I've tried this and the results are the same, when I sort the total column of visits, the rank column remains in sequence, if no one is sorted the rank column will automatically sort in the order of data md, and the total column of visits will not be sequential, if I sort 2 rank columns first then the total visit column, the result is the total visit column will not be sequential